# String manipulation with regex and nsarray and mutable strings in objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex, string, cocoa, nsarray

I'm trying to parse data from text file in a very customised format.

```
 Ronaldo : 1, Messi : 1, Owen,Beckham : 2, Mario|Terry : 1, Lampard,Pele : 3
```

THis is whats in the text file, and I capture it using the regex pattern: `([^\r\n\\s]*)\\s*:\\s*([^\r\n\\s]*) //objectiveC`

a simple `NSLog(@"%@ = %@", group1, growp2)` caputures between the `:` as keys and values.

```
Ronaldo = 1,
Messi = 1|2,
Owen,Beckham = 2
Mario|Terry = 1,
Lampard,Pele = 3
/* 
 `|` means "OR", Mario OR Terry = 1
 `,` means "AND", Lampard AND Pele = 3
 */
```

I wanted to now convert them into the following `NSArray`, which for the life of me, Im just clueless about.

```
array1 = ["Ronaldo=1" , "Messi=1" , "Owen,Becham=2", "Mario=1", "Lampard,Pele=3"]
array2 = ["Ronaldo=1", "Messi=1", "Owen,Becham=2", "Terry=1", "Lampard,Pele=3"]
```

What just happened is, the creation of two arrays based on the **`OR`** or **`|`**  character.

Since `Mario|Terry = 1`, I wanted a set of array that contain each of the two independently.

Similarly, if there are three choices in another set, `Mueller|Hargreves|Anelka`, i should have three array sets with each of those, and no array with all of them.

Somehow, I'm not unable to translate it into code, so far, i've tried many things, with no success. Complexities are cropping up as for loops. 
for instance.

this is within the `[NSRegularExpression  enumerateMatchesInString...]` code block

```
       for(NSString *player in OptionalPlayerArray)
       {
        NSMutableArray *optionalarr =[NSMutableArray new];


          for(NSString *value in valueChoices)
          {
            NSString *datastring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",player,value]
            [optionalarr addObject:[datastring]];                                 
            }

       }
```

You see a double for-Loop, The valueChoices array also accounts for a choice/option in value. like `Lampard = 1|2`.

EDIT:

The nested for-loop was intended to relate to the optional-values. Lampard=**`1|2`**. I thought this would be easy to do "too". I was so wrong. So please ignore the nested loop, I can live without optional-values and instead focus entirely on optional-keys: **`Lampard|Mario=1`**.

But that got me no where. Please let me know what my options are, perhaps a different regex-approach? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why? What are you going to do with the arrays when you have them?

Comment: I need to lay them out in a text file. After i get those arrays, i'll use `[NSArray componentsJoinedByString:..]` and save them to a text file. I need to present the data in that way.

Comment: It really isn't possible to give you a definitive answer.
a) you haven't specified why Messi = 1|2
b) you need more than two loops.  Every time you encounter an | in the keyside, you need to DUPLICATE all of your answer sets so far, once for each of the or'd values.

Comment: Yes, how about ignoring the value choice `Messi = 1|2` and just focus on the key choices? Even then its difficult, i assume?

Comment: @JeffLaing edited the part of the question about nested for-loop.

Comment: If you ignore the Messi=1|2, the problem seems quite simple. Iterate through each of the inputs, adding it to each of the answers that are currently in progress.  Anytime you find an input that contains an |, you need to replicate each of the answers so far, once for each of the alternatives.

The initial condition is mildly interesting in that you have zero answers, so special case that one to be an empty list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this isn't homework.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSArray *data = @[
                @"Ronaldo : 1",
                @"Messi : 1",
                @"Owen,Beckham : 2",
                @"Mario|Terry : 1",
                @"Lampard,Pele : 3",
                @"Wally|Molly|Golly : 5",
                @"Homework : 0"
    ];

    // prime answers with a single empty entry
    __block NSMutableArray *answers = [NSMutableArray array];
    [answers addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];

    NSRegularExpression *re;
    re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"([^\r\n\\s]*)\\s*:\\s*([^\r\n\\s]*)"
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:nil];
    for (NSString *line in data) {
        [re enumerateMatchesInString:line
                             options:0
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [line length])
                          usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
            {
                NSString *lhs = [line substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
                NSString *rhs = [line substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:2]];
                NSArray *players = [lhs componentsSeparatedByString:@"|"];
                if ([players count] == 1) {
                    NSString *p = [players objectAtIndex:0];
                    for (NSMutableArray *a in answers) {
                        [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",p,rhs]];
                    }
                } else {
                    NSMutableArray *newanswers = [NSMutableArray array];
                    for (NSString *p in players) {
                        NSMutableArray *pa = [NSMutableArray array];
                        for (NSMutableArray *a in answers) {
                            [pa addObject:[a mutableCopy]];
                        }
                        for (NSMutableArray *a in pa) {
                            [a addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%@",p,rhs]];
                        }
                        [newanswers addObjectsFromArray:pa];
                    }
                    answers = newanswers;
                }
            }
        ];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",answers);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your help really is appreciated. Somehow I knew i had to dive into alot of mutable arrays. `Homework != 1`!